# kohana - how to get _external error messages from a file

Tags: php, kohana

I am using Kohana's validation methods to ascertain that certain mandatory values are present inside a form. While validating  confirm_password the 'errors' method of ORM_Validation_Exception is returning array in the following format

```
array(1) (
    "_external" => array(1) (
        "password_confirm" => string(45) "password confirm must be the same as password"
    )
)
```

How can i make it follow the same convention as rest of the errors so that i can do the following  and just iterate through the errors in the view file.

```
 $Errors = $e->errors('user'); // inside the controller

<?php if ($Errors): ?>
<p class="message">Some errors were encountered, please check the details you entered.</p>
<ul class="errors">
<?php 
echo Debug::vars($Errors);
foreach ($Errors as $message): ?>
    <li><?php echo $message ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;
```

I have tried adding an _external file under messages(also tried placing it in /messages/model) folder, but it doesn't seem working. Should I call  `$Errors = $e->errors('_external')` to load the error messages, in that case all how can i load messages from 'User' file which contains rest of the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you translate the errors using a message file (which in your case should go in `messages/user/<model>/_external.php`), your `$Errors` array will still have the same structure i.e. external error messages will be in their own sub-array, `$Errors['_external']`.

If you need it 'flattened' I think you'll have to do that manually, e.g.:

```
// The next line is from your question
$Errors = $e->errors('user'); // inside the controller

// If there are any '_external' errors, we place them directly into $Errors
if (isset($Errors['_external']))
{
    // Keeps track of a possible edge case in which the _external
    // array has a key '_external'
    $double_external = isset($Errors['_external']['_external']);

    // Move the elements of the sub-array of external errors into the main array
    $Errors = array_merge_recursive($Errors, $Errors['_external']);

    // Remove the '_external' subarray, except in the edge case
    if (!$double_external)
    {
        unset($Errors['_external']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should merge them, as far ar I know there is no function or whatsoever in the framework which does this for you. Unfortunately.

```
$errors = $e->errors('user');
$errors = Arr::merge($errors, Arr::get($errors, '_external'));
unset($errors['_external']);
```